# Compress WAV PCM to Microsoft GSM 6.10 Audio Codec using C#

Tags: c#, gsm, pcm

Does any one know how to convert a uncompressed wave file in PCM format to a wav file compressed in GSM 6.10 Audio Codec?

Answer (score 2):

Try [How to convert to Gsm Wav file](http://alvas.net/alvas.audio,articles.aspx#how-to-convert-to-gsm-wav)

```
    static void ToWavWithGsm()
    {
        string fileName = @"e:\Down\male.wav";
        WaveReader wr = new WaveReader(File.OpenRead(fileName));
        IntPtr format = wr.ReadFormat();
        IntPtr formatGsm = AudioCompressionManager.GetCompatibleFormat(format,
            AudioCompressionManager.Gsm610FormatTag);
        byte[] dataGsm = AudioCompressionManager.ToFormat(wr, formatGsm);
        WaveWriter ww = new WaveWriter(File.Create(fileName + ".wav"),
            AudioCompressionManager.FormatBytes(formatGsm));
        ww.WriteData(dataGsm);
        ww.Close();
        wr.Close();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

IIRC, if you have the codec installed, [naudio](http://naudio.codeplex.com/) should be able to encode with it using `WaveFormatConversionStream`

Comment: Thanks for that I currently have a support ticket out for a problem I’m having doing this in there software. I'm looking for different way than naudio as I am under some pressure to achieve this. Let it be known that apart from this one problem it’s a create library.