# Decoding audio GSM 6.10 codec

Tags: c#, audio, gsm, decoding

How can I decode GSM 6.10 (Full-Rate) codec audio byte array on the fly in C#? I had some examples in C, Java even Haxe (https://github.com/francois2metz/WavPlayer/blob/master/org/tritonus/lowlevel/gsm/GSMDecoder.hx), but none of them works. Every time I try to play I get trash from my audio device.

My situation is that I receive bytes array of GSM 6.10 audio from the server, array size can be specified, but how can i decode it and write to the device?

Comment: Please, do not include information about a language used in a question title unless it wouldn't make sense without it. Tags serve this purpose.

Comment: Does the answer to this question help (not sure if it is also valide for decoding): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9415358/c-sharp-compress-wav-pcm-to-microsoft-gsm-6-10-audio-codec?rq=1

Comment: The solution is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22435784/decoding-gsm-6-10-parts-in-naudio)