# Decoding GSM 6.10 parts in NAudio

Tags: c#, audio, gsm, naudio, decoding

How can I decode GSM 6.10 (Full-Rate) codec audio byte array on the fly in NAudio? Sources says that wave decoding is processed at one time and I can't process several bytes of wave (fix me if I'm wrong).

My situation is that I receive bytes array of GSM 6.10 audio from the server, array size can be specified, but how can i decode it and write to the device?

Edit:

What am I doing wrong?
According to Mark's solution this should work but all I hear is distorted sounds:

```
        WaveOut waveO = new WaveOut();
        BufferedWaveProvider waveP = new BufferedWaveProvider(new WaveFormat(8000, 16, 1));
        waveO.Init(waveP);
        waveO.Play();

        INetworkChatCodec cod = new Gsm610ChatCodec();

        new Thread(delegate()
        {
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://www.nch.com.au/acm/8kgsm.wav");
            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
            using (Stream resStream = response.GetResponseStream())
            {
                if (resStream.CanRead)
                {
                    byte[] buf = new byte[65];
                    int count = 0;
                    do
                    {
                        count = resStream.Read(buf, 0, buf.Length);
                        if (count != 0)
                        {
                            byte[] decoded = cod.Decode(buf, 0, count);
                            waveP.AddSamples(decoded, 0, decoded.Length);
                            Thread.Sleep(50);
                        }
                    }
                    while (count > 0);
                }
            }
        }).Start();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with the `AcmStream` class, passing in `Gsm610WaveFormat` as the source format and 8kHz 16 bit mono as the output format. The network chat demo in the NAudio source code shows this in action to decode on the fly.

Comment: Are those decoders in network chat demo differ somehow from those in wave play example? Sound is correct in playback example but when decoding bytes arrays all I hear is mess. For example this file: nch.com.au/acm/8kgsm.wav What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You have to get the WaveFormat exactly right. Check what the WaveFormat structure actually contains in that WAV file

Comment: WaveFormat seems to be exactly the same. Could You please provide in a free time a working example of playing (from disk) GSM 6.10 wave file ([link](http://nch.com.au/acm/8kgsm.wav)) decoded from byte arrays? I think I'm missing something and such help would be very appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Please check what is wrong in the edited part of my question. Thanks.

Comment: you're receiving a WAV file, not just raw GSM6.10. The whole WAV file should not be given to the codec, just the data portion of the file

Comment: Ahh, stupid me! Thanks, that really does the trick. Thank You Mark.